# NPM Worker not found

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules, vtk.js

I try to duplicate an existing library from npm (final goal is to edit an algorithm). The original library used is [vtk.js](https://github.com/kitware/vtk-js). The only component I will try to duplicate localy is the [PaintFilter](https://github.com/Kitware/vtk-js/tree/master/Sources/Filters/General/PaintFilter) worker.

So I duplicate the `PaintFilter.js` in my own structure and it's working fine as it use the original worker from `vtk.js`.

No problem with this

```
import PaintFilterWorker from 'vtk.js/Sources/Filters/General/PaintFilter/PaintFilter.worker';
```

But once I try to use my own worker (currently a copy pasted of the original, located in the same directory as my local `PaintFilter`) with this command

```
import PaintFilterWorker from './PaintFilter.worker';
```

I have an error

```
WARNING in ./resources/assets/js/PaintFilter/PaintFilter.js
28:19-36 "export 'default' (imported as 'PaintFilterWorker') was not found in './PaintFilter.worker'.
```

As I use the exact same code as the original one I don't understand why it's not working.

I tried to rename it but still have the same issue.
I'm starting with npm and js module so maybe I missed something. Sorry if this is the case.

Comment: Could you share the code of your `'./PaintFilter.worker'` code ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the same as this one : https://github.com/Kitware/vtk-js/blob/master/Sources/Filters/General/PaintFilter/PaintFilter.worker.js

Comment: Weird, it has indeed no `export` statement, so it's natural your error, but it's weird that it works in your other use case, if that's the exact same file.

Comment: Indeed, and the whole `vtk.js` library is using worker like this without any issue